# How to display the first page of an uploaded pdf as a thumbnail with PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

I am working on an e-learning portal, but I am finding it difficult to display the first page of the uploaded pdf as a thumbnail.

Any hints, assistance or suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: what technology you are using ? php, .net ?

Comment: go for imagemagick or pdflib extenstion for php.

Comment: @hardik what technology??  is already tagged

Answer (score 1):

[ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) is very good at exporting and scaling PDF to PNG/JPG/GIF. Most hosters support it, this is the fastest and simplest way.

Comment: Thanks, but do I need Ghotscript before this will work. because I am this error: unable to open image `test.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638

Comment: Wring path, double check your calls

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/imagick)

### Example:

```
<?php
$imagePreview = new imagick('file.pdf[0]');
$imagePreview->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
header( "Content-Type: image/jpeg" );
echo $imagePreview;
```

Comment: Thanks, but do I need Ghotscript before this will work. because I am this error: unable to open image `test.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638